# Updating multiple Databases with Hibernate after entity changes

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

in my current Hibernate implementation I have set the property `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` to update. Now I changed one of my entity classes to feature two more attributes/columns but the schema is not updated in all databases? Via web I access a management database with tables that contain links to the other databases that contain actual data. In the management database it was updated correctly, but in all other databases not. Now if i want to view some of the contents it throws a render error, because the columns are not there. Is there a way to force hibernate to update this entity in all databases? Or do i have to open them somwhow to let hibernate apply the changes?

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: You have to connect hibernate directly to the other databases. Hibernate only knows the management database, but not the other ones

Comment: @XtremeBaumer ok so how I do this then? Any tips?

Comment: Same as you connect to the management database. My tip is to manually create and update tables. Hibernate generated tables might not be the best

Comment: @XtremeBaumer ok. Unfortunately I have 500+ databases. Would it be doable to write an SQL-File where I connect to each of the databases and use an alter table command with the needed parameters?

Comment: Hard to tell what would be the best course of action. Perhaps you want to set up replication. Perhaps a script would be sufficient. But without knowing the actual setup and what databases are use for what purpose etc. it is impossible. That would also far exceed the scope of this question